# Unlock ssh key on login

Tags: ssh, command-line, login, password, ssh-agent

When in the graphical environment, `seahorse` unlocks my ssh key (locked with a passphrase) so I can ssh to another host without entering a passphrase.

But when on the command line, I am still asked for such a passphrase.

Is there a way to have ssh-agent unlock my key on login the way seahorse does? Also, what is the proper way to start ssh-agent on login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt install keychain
```

and add

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ] ; then
    keychain -q ~/.ssh/id_rsa;
fi
. ~/.keychain/$(hostname)-sh 2> /dev/null
```

to ~/.bashrc

https://linux.die.net/man/1/keychain

Comment: But I already have ssh-agent installed, as well as seahorse, wouldn't in be a third key agent?... Can't I just use ssh-agent?

Besides, does seahorse use ssh-agent/gpg-agent to manage ssh/gpg keys or does it bring its own agent with it?

Comment: @Ninguém  "keychain - re-use ssh-agent ... between logins" you can use just ssh-agent if you want to be asked for a password on every login.

Comment: Hum! In that case...